# Find a string with or without space in oracle using like or regex

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a string which contains specific 'winner code' which needs to be matched exactly but in the database some records contains spaces and extra characters within 'winners code' and if I use 'like operator' it only returns the matching criteria. I want to use one simplified query which can return all the records if it contains the winner code.Please find below my query and details

Winner code - أ4 ب3 ج10

Records with spaces -  أ4 ب 3 ج 10

Records with extra character - (أ(4) ب(3) ج(10

My Query - 
`SELECT COLUMN_NAME,
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE 
((COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%أ4%ب3%ج10%') or(COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%أ 4%ب 3%ج 10%'))`

The above query returns with and without space data as its matching the criteria.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your need, you may try :

```
with test(str) as (
    select '10X3Y4Z' from dual union all
    select '10 X 3 Y 4 Z' from dual union all
    select '(10)X(3)Y(4)Z' from dual union all
    select '10@X3Y4  Z' from dual union all
    select '10 @ X3Y4Z' from dual )
select str
from test
where regexp_instr(str, '10[ |\)]{0,1}X[ |\(]{0,1}3[ |\)]{0,1}Y[ |\(]{0,1}4[ |\)]{0,1}Z') != 0
```

This matches your "winner code" ( I used different characters to simplify my test) even if the numbers are surrounded by '()' or a single space.
This can be re-written in a more compact way, but I believe this form is clear enough; it uses regular expressions like `[ |\)]{0,1}` to match a space or a parenthesis, with zero or one occurrence.